# Validating username, password, and email in PHP

Tags: php, validation, error-handling

Let's pretend the following:

```
 <?php
 // Functions to validate/sanitize user input
 function validateUsername() {
    // If accepted, return true, else return false
 }
 function validatePassword() {
    // If accepted, return true, else return false
 }
 function validateEmail() {
    // If accepted, return true, else return false
 }
```

This is how I handle user input:

```
// Getting all user input
$values = $_POST['values'];

$error = false;

if (!validateUsername($username) && $error === false) {
    $errorMessage = "Username can't contain special characters";
    $error = true;
}
if (!validatePassword($password) && $error === false) {
    $errorMessage = "Password is'nt secure enought";
    $error = true;
}
if (!validateEmail($email) && $error === false) {
    $errorMessage = "Email is not correctly formatted";
    $error = true;
}

if ($error === true) {
    echo $errorMessage;
} else {

    // Do something

}
?>
```

But I'm sure there is a better approach. What is the best (or a good) way to handle user input messages/errors?

Also I've read a tutorial (which unfortunately I can't find anymore) where it was recommended to give the users hints and tips about their input, instead of giving them a big bold red warning.

For example to accept not only `1234 AB` (Dutch postcodes), but also `1234ab`, `1234AB` and `1234 ab` and let the script convert it to the official notation `1234 AB`.

Comment: well, doesn't that depend on what kind of project you're working on? procedural vs oop, using a framework and if so, what framework?

Comment: No framework and procedurial (functional) coding style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this below class will help you.  Put this `Valiation` class in file named as `Validation.php` file.

```
<?php 
/** 
 * This class will provide server side validation for different rules with custom 
 * provided message for respective rule. 
 * 
 * @author: Alankar More. 
 */ 
class Validation 
{ 
    /** 
     * Posted values by the user 
     * 
     * @var array 
     */ 
    protected static $_values; 

    /** 
     * Rules set for validation 
     * 
     * @var array 
     */ 
    protected static $_rules; 

    /** 
     * Error messages 
     * 
     * @var array 
     */ 
    protected static $_messages; 

    /** 
     * To send response 
     * 
     * @var array 
     */ 
    protected static $_response = array(); 

    /** 
     * For storing HTMl objects 
     * 
     * @var array 
     */ 
    protected static $_elements; 

    /** 
     * Html object 
     * 
     * @var string 
     */ 
    protected static $_inputElement; 

    /** 
     * Value of Html object 
     * 
     * @var mixed (string|boolean|integer|double|float) 
     */ 
    protected static $_elementValue; 

    /** 
     * Name of validation rule 
     * 
     * @var string 
     */ 
    protected static $_validationRule; 

    /** 
     * Value of validation rule 
     * 
     * @var mixed (string|boolean|integer|double|float) 
     */ 
    protected static $_ruleValue; 

    /** 
     * Initializing class 
     * 
     * @param array $inputArray 
     * @param array $values 
     */ 
    public static function _initialize(array $inputArray, array $values) { 
        self::$_values = $values; 
        self::$_response = array(); 

        self::generateArrays($inputArray); 
        return self::applyValidation(); 
    } 

    /** 
     * Separating rules and values 
     * 
     * @param array $input 
     */ 
    public static function generateArrays(array $input) { 
        self::$_messages = $input['messages']; 
        self::$_rules = $input['rules']; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Applying validation for the form values 
     * 
     */ 
    public static function applyValidation() { 
        foreach (self::$_rules as $rk => $rv) { 
            $_element = self::$_rules[$rk]; 
            if (is_array($_element)) { 
                foreach ($_element as $key => $ruleValue) { 
                    if (!self::$_elements[$rk]['inValid']) { 
                        $method = "_" . $key; 
                        self::$_inputElement = $rk; 
                        self::$_elementValue = self::$_values[$rk]; 
                        self::$_validationRule = $key; 
                        self::$_ruleValue = $ruleValue; 

                        self::$method(); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        if (count(self::$_response) == 0) { 
            self::$_response['valid'] = true; 
        } 

        return self::$_response; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Method to check wheather the input element holds the value. 
     * If not then assingn message which is set by the user. 
     * 
     */ 
    protected static function _required() { 
        if (self::$_ruleValue) { 
            if (trim(self::$_elementValue) == NULL && 
                strlen(self::$_elementValue) == 0) { 
                self::setErrorMessage("Field Required"); 
                self::setInvalidFlag(true); 
            } else { 
                self::setInvalidFlag(false); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Maximum length of input 
     * 
     */ 
    protected static function _maxLength() { 
        if (self::$_ruleValue) { 
            if (strlen(trim(self::$_elementValue)) > self::$_ruleValue) { 
                self::setErrorMessage("Enter at most " . self::$_ruleValue . " charachters only"); 
                self::setInvalidFlag(true); 
            } else { 
                self::setInvalidFlag(false); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Minimum length of input 
     * 
     */ 
    protected static function _minLength() { 
        if (self::$_ruleValue) { 
            if (self::$_ruleValue > strlen(trim(self::$_elementValue))) { 
                self::setErrorMessage("Enter at least " . self::$_ruleValue . " charachters "); 
                self::setInvalidFlag(true); 
            } else { 
                self::setInvalidFlag(false); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Allow alphabets only 
     * 
     */ 
    protected static function _number() { 
        if (self::$_ruleValue) { 
            $str = filter_var(trim(self::$_elementValue), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); 
            if (!preg_match('/[0-9]/', $str)) { 
                self:: setErrorMessage("Enter numbers only"); 
                self::setInvalidFlag(true); 
            } else { 
                self::setInvalidFlag(false); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Allow alphabets only 
     * 
     */ 
    protected static function _alphabetsOnly() { 
        if (self::$_ruleValue) { 
            $str = filter_var(trim(self::$_elementValue), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
            if (!preg_match('/[a-zA-z]/', $str)) { 
                self:: setErrorMessage("Enter alphabates only"); 
                self::setInvalidFlag(true); 
            } else { 
                self::setInvalidFlag(false); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Allow alphabets and numbers only 
     * 
     */ 
    protected static function _alphaNumeric(){ 
        if (self::$_ruleValue) { 
            $str = trim(self::$_elementValue); 
            if (!preg_match('/[a-zA-z0-9]/', $str)) { 
                self:: setErrorMessage("Alphanumeric only"); 
                self::setInvalidFlag(true); 
            } else { 
                self::setInvalidFlag(false); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * To check enter email is valid 
     * 
     */ 
    protected static function _email(){ 
       if (self::$_ruleValue) { 
            $str = filter_var(trim(self::$_elementValue), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); 
            if (!$str) { 
                self:: setErrorMessage("Enter valid email"); 
                self::setInvalidFlag(true); 
            } else { 
                self::setInvalidFlag(false); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * To check enter url is valid 
     * 
     */ 
    protected static function _url(){ 
       if (self::$_ruleValue) { 
            $str = filter_var(trim(self::$_elementValue), FILTER_VALIDATE_URL); 
            if (!$str) { 
                self:: setErrorMessage("Enter valid URL"); 
                self::setInvalidFlag(true); 
            } else { 
                self::setInvalidFlag(false); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Setting invalid flag for every element 
     * 
     * @param boolean $flag 
     */ 
    private static function setInvalidFlag($flag) { 
        self::$_elements[self::$_inputElement]['inValid'] = $flag; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Setting error message for the input element 
     * 
     * @param string $message 
     */ 
    private static function setErrorMessage($message) { 
        if (self::$_messages[self::$_inputElement][self::$_validationRule]) { 
            $message = self::$_messages[self::$_inputElement][self::$_validationRule]; 
        } 
       array_push(self::$_response, ucfirst($message)); 
    } 
}
```

You can use this class in your application as below:

```
<form name="frmTest" id="frmTest" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value = "" />
    <button name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>

<?php
require_once 'validation.php';
// Rules specification.
$rules = array('method' => 'POST',
    'rules' => array('first_name' => array('required' => true)
    ),
    'messages' => array('first_name' => array('required' => 'Please enter first name')
    )
);

$userPostedData = $_POST;
$response = Validation::_initialize($rules, $userPostedData);

// if some error messages are present.
if (!$response['valid']) {
    // it will give you the array with error messages.
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
} else {
    // all applied validations are passed. You can deal with your submitted information now.
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
}
?>
```

Comment: Nice! But, why `'url' => true` for a first_name?

Comment: Actually it was for demonstration that we can also use the validation for URL. Ah ! but it is not currently useful in the current example I have given. I have remove that.

Comment: Ah okay, then i understand:p very nice class!

Comment: Would you care to explain this class? Why is it important to use a class here? What mistakes dit the OP make? Just posting a class is not very useful for making OP a better coder. Also, why is there a static `initialize` method? Why not just use a constructor and lose the static stuff.

Comment: Yes you are right , we can use construct. and that would be more better way. I have created class here because you can keep all validations in single class and you can use it according to the rule that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

*Parse Error on line 3* (by the way)

You can code it however you want. Think like the user: the user will never see your code and is only interested in his current task (in this case, to create an account). So build you PHP script in a way you are currently understanding because you may have to fix bugs.

But to answer you question:

There are uncountable ways to do what you want to do. For example, you can store functions in arrays and use them with `foreach`.

```
<?php

# Functions to validate/sanitize user input
$validate['name'] = function()
{
    echo "checking UserName...<br />\n";
    return true;
};
$validate['password'] = function()
{
    echo "checking Password...<br />\n";
    return true;
};
$validate['mail'] = function()
{
    echo "checking Email...<br />\n";
    return false;
};
$validate['age'] = function()
{
    echo "checking Age...<br />\n";
    return true;
};
$validate['country'] = function()
{
    echo "checking Country...<br />\n";
    return true;
};


# loop for every $validate function
foreach ($validate as $key => $check)
{
    if( $check() ) # $check is the validate function
    {
        # may some code before continuing
    }
    else
    {
        # your big bold red warning
        echo "<h1 style=\"colour:red;\">";
        echo "your $key should be validate";
        echo "</h1>";

        # you can stop the loop with break if you want
        # break;
    }
}

?>
```